# Conversion of time series into frequency domain using the FFT

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, fft, frequency

I have a time series which I would like to convert into the frequency domain, And I am using the code below but I think I am getting confused with the frequency distribution on x axis with `linspace()` and with y variable in the code. What correction would be needed for this code?

About the time series:

- sample rate = 96000
- len(data) = 40000000

  ```
    data = time_series

    y= fft(data)

    sample = len(data)
    N = 96000 # sampling rate
    frequency = np.linspace (0.0, sample, int (N/2))
    y= 2/N * (y[0:np.int (N/2)]).astype(np.float64)
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
    plt.suptitle('Time and freq ', fontsize='30')
    axs[0].plot(df.iloc[:,0])
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Time', fontsize ='20')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Q0', fontsize='20')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('freq', fontsize ='20')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('feature', fontsize='20')
    axs[1].plot(frequency[0:len(frequency)], y[0:len(y)], color = 'g')
    plt.show()
  ```

Comment: length of the entire time data = 40000000

Comment: Please include your import statement, so we know what functions you are calling. You should  use `fftfreq` to get the frequencies associated with each sample in the frequency domain.